# Docker build is stuck on Webpack Compile, when deploying onto server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean, strapi

I have an app that is using strapi in a docker container. I was running the app via `docker compose up --build`, which would build the app first then run it.

The problem I had was that, while this works on my home computer, when I tried it on the server, it would instead just hang forever while trying to compile the webpack.

Logs also failed to show anything interesting, which left me a bit confounded on what to do next.

Comment: Can you build the image locally (or via a CI system), push it to a repository, and then just run it on the server without building it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did eventually solve this, with help from the folks on the Strapi discord.

The answer turned out to be that the app was running out of memory during build. The Docker docs recommend a minimum of 2gb, while the basic digital-oceans droplet only has 1gb.

To solve the problem, I instead split up the build process with a script:

`restart-server.sh`

```
#! /bin/sh
cd /srv/deployed_project

# close any running containers
docker compose down

# build each dockerfile individually, to avoid overloading memory.
cd /srv/deployed_project/nginx
docker build -f nginx.Dockerfile --target production .

cd /srv/deployed_project/strapi
docker build -f strapi.Dockerfile --target production .

cd /srv/deployed_project/nextjs
docker build -f nextjs.Dockerfile --target production .

# -d detaches the containers
cd /srv/deployed_project
docker compose up -d
```

Comment: Just FYI. Building the container on the server is a bit of an anti-pattern to start with. Using docker hub or setting up a container registry is a more robust option. Allows you to build/push images from anywhere.

Comment: @super Those are great ideas too. :) Unfortunately they both would cost extra money in this case. Digital-oceans container registry only has 500mb of space and 1 repo allowed before you have to pay, while the docker hub free tier doesn't allow private repos.

I will keep them in mind if I come across this problem again in the future though, thanks!

Comment: If money is the issue, you can always upload images to your server using simple ftp, scp or similar. You can even do it automatically from github actions etc.